# Python and Beautiful Soup: How to download files with original filenames?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to download some files and all links end in `.../download`.
Therefore I don't know what the original filenames and, more importantly, the original extensions are.

**How can I get the original names and extensions of the files in this situation?**

If I'm downloading manually, I get the original filenames and formats.
If I'm defining a name and extension it's all going nice and well.
But sometimes not all files have the same extension, therefore I cannot predefine them.

code excerpt below

```
with open("page.html") as html_page:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'lxml')

links = []
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

for item in links:
    if str(item).endswith('download'):
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(str(item), 'pics/' + str(links.index(item))+'.png')
```

Comment: Check the response headers. The filename will be in there. It's a lot easier to use `requests` for this than `urllib`.

Comment: If you use `response = requests.get(url)`  then you can use `response.headers.get('Content-Type')` to check the type and then `with open(filename, 'wb') as f: f.write(response.content)`. You can't be sure of it, but sometimes the filename can be buried in the headers, too - like if `url` was [this link](https://drive.google.com/u/1/uc?id=12PAxMjuUGyv-vXNakVK7xMrI0X3_yN3q&export=download), then *`r.headers.get('Content-Disposition')`* would return *`attachment; filename="045632_2023.pdf"; filename*=UTF-8\'\'045632_2023.pdf`* - you could check your download response for anything like that...